# Creating complete structure from multiple JSON files

Tags: json, pyspark

I have six types of JSON files (each for various booking statuses) with me that all needs to be loaded into a single database table using PySpark. The files have many common fields among them. However, depending the status, some JSONs will have some extra fields whereas some won't.

Since all of them finally needs to be loaded into a single table, I need to read them using a specific schema. That way, if a JSON does not have one of the required fields, when that field is fetched, it can return a null value instead of throwing an error that the field does not exist.

Problem is, client cannot provide the master structure using which I can read all the six files. Is there an easy way to compare the six types of JSONs and create a master JSON structure out of them?

Comment: Do the JSON files change over time or does their structure remain the same?

Comment: The structure would remain the same. But it is not necessary that every json file will have all the keys.

Comment: If the structure of the JSON files remains the same, and each record within a JSON file has all attributes, I would go for getting the first record of each JSON file and extract the corresponding structure. Having all structures, it should be fairly simple to get their union.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant. The issue I am facing is: let's say I have 10 columns in the table I am trying to insert into. One type of JSON has 15 fields and I can select the required 10 from it. The next type of JSON has only 5 fields. So when I try to fetch the other 5 that's not available in it, it will throw an error. Hence, I am trying to make a master schema json using which I can read both the JSONs without issues.

Comment: My response adresses the process of creating the *master structure* by using plain python without pyspark in the first place in order to instantiate the required schema.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I am fairly new to coding. Will give that a try.